# WindowsFormsHost causing System.Windows.Forms.Button.Click event to not fire

Tags: wpf, button, windowsformshost

I'm converting a windows forms application into WPF, and am re-using some of the winform controls for the first part of the conversion.

To host the winform controls, I'm using WindowsFormsHost, and what appears to be happening is that the enter keypress is not causing Button.Click event to be fired on winforms buttons (however, clicking with the mouse and spacebar still works).

You can reproduce this behavior by doing the following:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"  
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <WindowsFormsHost>
        <wf:Button Text="Hello" Click="Button_Click_1"  />
    </WindowsFormsHost>
</Grid>
```

I was thinking of adding an event handler to the WindowsFormsHost to call Button.PerformClick if enter was pressed and a button was focused, but I feel like there must be something I'm overlooking with *why* enter isn't causing the button click to occur.